# Nested model in angular2

Tags: angular

I have the parent user model like below:

user.ts

```
   export class User {
           employeeModel: employee = new Employee();
   }
```

and I have a child model named employee.ts

```
   export class Employeee {
           name: string ;
           age: string ;
           position: string ;
   }
```

In my component.ts I instantiate the parent model like:

`model: User = new User();`

And in my template:

```
<input type="text"  [(ngModel)]="model.employeeModel.name">
```

Using that codes I get :
      `Cannot read property 'name' of undefined`.

What is wrong with my codes?

Comment: hey are you there??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your user object should be of below type

```
 export class User {
           employee: Employeee 
   } 

   export class Employeee {
           name: string ;
           age: string ;
           position: string ;
   }
```

You have instantiated only the model and not the sub properties.

```
model: User = new User();
```

So you should be doing this

declaration

```
model : User = { };
```

Instancitating

```
this.model.employee ={
    name: '',
    age: '',
    position: -1
}
```